# Change text box value according to input parameter in angular

Tags: angularjs

Currently I am using the code below, and it is working fine.  But I want to remove the if statements.

```
$scope.setValue = function (dataPut,dataRecive) {
    if(dataPut=='profData')
        $scope.formData.profData=dataRecive;    
    else if(dataPut=='cartData')
        $scope.formData.cartData=dataRecive;    
    else if(dataPut=='buyflowData')
        $scope.formData.buyflowData=dataRecive;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) property accessors like

```
$scope.setValue = function(dataPut, dataRecive) {
  $scope.formData[dataPut] = dataRecive;
}
```

However note: it will create property if it's not defined for `$scope.formData` .

```js
var formData = {};
var setValue = function(dataPut, dataRecive) {
  formData[dataPut] = dataRecive;
}
var value = prompt("Enter a value");
setValue('value', value);
console.log(formData)
```